# Creating user specific authentication methods in SSH

Tags: authentication, key-management, ssh, key-generation, server

1. I have configured sshd on an Ubuntu server to use key authentication and it is working fine.
2. I had to disable password authentication for key authentication to work.
3. Server is always accessed via remote terminals or putty.

Now all user accounts are able to login with the authentication key and passphrase. But now I want to create only one new user without key authentication. So how should I go about doing this in such a way that does not hamper other users who are using key authentication.

Comment: It is not correct that you must disable password authentication for key authentication to work.  However, disabling password authentication is usually a good thing anyway (unless you have a lot of trust in your users to choose excellent passwords -- and possibly even then).  In any case, you have received good answers about how to disable password authentication for all but a single user, and that is probably the right strategy to follow.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can use `Match` in [`sshd_config`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sshd_config%205) to select individual users to alter the `PasswordAuthentication` directive for. Enter these `Match` rules at the **bottom** of [`sshd_config`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sshd_config%205) file ( generally `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` )

```
Match User root,foo,bar
    PasswordAuthentication no
Match User Rishee
    PasswordAuthentication yes
```

This would give root, foo and bar key authentication, and Rishee password authentication.

An alternative is to match by negation, like this:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
Match User *,!root
    PasswordAuthentication yes
```

In this case, everyone except root gets password authentication.

*Note: The `*,` syntax is necessary, as wildcard and negation syntax is only parsed in comma-separated lists.*

You can also match by group:

```
Match Group usergroup
    PasswordAuthentication no
```

[Reason](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config) for entering `Match` at the bottom of the file:

> If all of the criteria on the Match line are satisfied, the keywords on the following lines override those set in the global section of the config file, until either another >Match line or the end of the file

Comment: I didn't even know that was possible, cool :D

Comment: @Polynomial I created a user called auditor with a password and then I updated the /etc/ssh/sshd_config with the below entry. : <br />Match User auditor
    PasswordAuthentication yes <br /> then tried to connect to the server with putty it said server refused connection No authentication method supported.

Comment: I'd need to see the full set of authentication rules to help really. Could you stick it on a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) for me? Though, at this point, your question might be better suited to [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/).

Comment: @Polynomial [Pastbin for sshd_config](http://pastebin.com/q70D4Ww1) I have also asked it on askubuntu + Superuser + ServerFault

Comment: Try inverting the way you've written it -> http://pastebin.com/h5bgWFrr

Comment: @Rishee you need to restart sshd for the changes to take effect.

Comment: @Maerlyn I do that after every change... but thanks :)

Comment: There's an error in your answer. You can't use `Match User !root` You have to use `Match User *,!root`

Comment: @EdwardNedHarvey This answer is 4 years old, it may have changed since then. Feel free to propose an edit.

Comment: Pretty sure I just proposed an edit. The line `Match User !root` doesn't work, because you need to put the `*,` in there.

Comment: @EdwardNedHarvey I meant an actual edit proposal through the StackExchange functionality.

Comment: For those who are also wondering: a match block can be ended with `Match all`.

Comment: This is great, I used it for AuthenticationMethods and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

You can enable password and key-authentication at the same time, they are not exclusive.

Comment: But they're not selective. (EG. Not multifactuor) It allows multiple single factors.  Though redhat fixed [that](http://www.nzinfosec.com/redhat-adds-multi-factor-authentication-to-ssh/)